# How can I restore all hidden subdirectories with configuration files that were lost when I completely wiped out my home directory?

Tags: configuration, home-directory

My `/home` directory was on the separate partition. By mistake I destroyed all the data on it. Now it's resized and formatted. It contains no directories but empty lost+found.

So I lost config data for soo many packages and I guess some packages could not work, or could work wrong. Am I right?

Is there a way to restore those many hidden subdirectories that packages created during installation? I suppose they'll be recreated if I managed to reinstall all installed packages.

- Server 10.04 LTS,
- `/etc/skel` is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-installing packages is not going to help as the . directories are automatically created when you use a package. You can start with `cp /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.bashrc` . Other then that, most of the . directories will be auto generated and you should not have lost anything other then various settings or configurations.

Comment: `/etc/bash.bashrc` will be sourced anyway when Bash starts. You can test this by checking that `command_not_found` works (`/etc/bash.bashrc` is the only config file that pulls this in). You can stop it being used by setting PS1 to an empty string when launching a shell, since, unlike `~/.bashrc`, it checks whether the shell is interactive by determining whether it has PS1 [Here's a demo](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9twV5bctxh/). So copying `/etc/bash.bashrc` to `~/.bashrc` doesn't do anything useful :(